Characters with all higher exterior powers irreducible
Let $G$ be a finite group and we take for the field the complex numbers.
Call an irreducible character $\xi$ with degree $m$ of $G$ perfect, if all exterior powers $\bigwedge\nolimits^k \xi$ are irreducible for $k=1,\dotsc,m$.

Question 1: Can perfect irreducible characters be characterised in an easy way?


Question 2: What are the perfect irreducible characters for the symmetric group?

A famous example is the standard representation, but there are more. For example $S_6$ has 6 such irreducible perfect characters.

Question 3: What are the finite groups having a faithful irreducible character that is perfect? For $2$-groups the number of such groups seems rather small and starts for 2-groups with $n \geq 2$ elements with 1,1,3,6,9,12,15.


The standard representation of $S_n$ is not irreducible. I think you mean the reflection representation, with character $\chi^{(n-1,1)}$.

@RichardStanley This is called the standard representation in some books, for example the one of Lorenz. It is the representation $V$ such that $M \cong V \oplus K$, where $M$ is the natural representation of the symmetric group given by the operation on the set ${1,...,n}$.

For an irreducible of degree $d$ to have this property, the sum of the squares of the $\binom{d}{i}$ with $2i\leqslant d$ has to be at most the group order. Now look at faithful irreducibles of $S_n$ that are not associated to $(n-1,1)$ or $(2,1^{n-2})$. For $n=7$ and $n=8$ the smallest have dimension $14$. If $n\geqslant 9$, the smallest are $(n-2,2)$ and $(2^2,1^{n-4})$, with dimension $n(n-3)/2$. I'm pretty sure this is already too big for the sum of the squares to be at most $n!$. See Sloane A277247.

This is supposed to be an answer to the second of your two (now three) questions.

The upshot is that the dimension has to be very small compared with the group order, so it will be a rare phenomenon.

For $d$ odd, $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor d/2} \binom{d}{i}^2$ is $\binom{2d-1}{d-1}$. For $d$ even, it is $(1/2)(\binom{2d}{d} + \binom{d}{d/2}^2)$. Either way, roughly $4^d$.

It looks like $S_n \ltimes C^n$, for $C$ any cyclic group, might be another example. And some small variants on this: $S_n \ltimes C^{n-1}$, $A_n \ltimes C^n$ and $A_n \ltimes C^{n-1}$.

How about the 6 dimensional representation of $6!\operatorname{\rm U}_4(3)$? I suspect this is an example, but I didn't do the computation.

Indeed, for any complex reflection group, the reflection representation has this property. See the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382199/exterior-power-representation-of-s-n
